# Recover deleted mailbox and user- no AD recycle bin

Tags: active-directory, exchange, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I deleted a users mailbox in the ECP- AD user was of course also deleted. The recycle bin is not enabled.

Is the only way to recover the user and mailbox with an authoritative restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't restore the mailbox by restoring the user account. If you don't have a backup of the mailbox then see this link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863438(v=exchg.150).aspx

2. You can restore the deleted user account with the ADResore utility from Sysinternals:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963906.aspx

Comment: The ADRestore has been last updated in 2006. 
Although the article includes support for Windows 2008 R2, I would consider it's usage as a bit risky and double-check if it will work properly in your environment.

Comment: ADRestore isn't doing anything that you can't do yourself with NTDSUTIL (which isn't deprecated). ADRestore is just simplifying the process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware apart from pulling the data from a backup you will have to use Authoritative Restore. Definitely interested in seeing i there is an alternative myself.